# Checking for an empty ScriptParameter containing text

Tags: filemaker

I am working on FileMaker 14 and am using ScriptParameters.  In my parameters I use text, not numbers.  I am looking for a way to calculate whether a parameter is empty or not, but the code below returns a 0 value (false) if there is text in ScriptParameter or not:

```
If [ isEmpty ( Get ( ScriptParamter ) ) ]
```

The help docs in FileMaker do say that IsEmpty will return a value of 0 if the argument is text.  So obviously I am looking for a different calculation or something.  Ideas?

Thanks
GW

Comment: Please try and provide a better description than "doesn't work". You may also get better answers if you explain what are you actually trying to accomplish, instead of just describing what you have done.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more clear that I always get a 0 value with or without text

Comment: "*I always get a 0 value with or without text*" That's not possible.

Comment: You need to confirm your assumptions. If `IsEmpty` is returning `1`, then the argument you're passing isn't empty. You can confirm this by perhaps seeing what `Get ( ScriptParameter )` is using FileMaker Advance's Data Viewer, using `Show Custom Dialog` to display the value or checking that `Length ( Get ( ScriptParameter ) ) = 0`.

Answer (score 3):

FileMaker's IsEmpty() function absolutely returns TRUE (1) if a text argument is truly empty. If you're getting false, there's *something* in your script parameter.

It looks like you might be passing multiple values in your script parameter (based on your use of the plural "script parameters"). If so, your script parameter will never evaluate to true, because of the presence of one or more carriage returns. If you need to pass multiple values, you'll need to first extract a given value using GetValue( Get(ScriptParameter); ), which gets the nth line of text without a trailing carriage return, then test the extracted value.

If that's not right (and you're only passing a single value), this likely means you're passing invisible characters in your script parameter you're not aware of. To test, you can use Length( Get(ScriptParameter) ) to test how many characters FileMaker "sees" in your script parameter. To quickly get a handle on invisible characters, you might use Code( Get(ScriptParameter) ), which will return the ASCII codes for each character. This can quickly reveal if you have spaces, tabs, returns, etc.

Comment: I see what I did.  I had my bool values mixed up, a sort of binary dyslexia.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> The help docs in FileMaker do say that IsEmpty will return a value of
>   0 if the argument is text.

No, that's most certainly **not true**. `IsEmpty()` will return a value of
0 if the argument is empty. If your parameter is of type text, then `IsEmpty()` will return 0 if and only if the parameter is a string of zero length.